# jQuery calling function after ajax load

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have this function being declared on initial page load.

```
$.fn.tester = function() {
    alert("Test");  
}
```

I'm then making an ajax call using load()

In the ajax page returned, I am trying to use this function and am giving the error
Object # has no method 'tester'.

I am new to jQuery and unsure where to begin to fix this.

Comment: Please include the code which throws the error.

Comment: First, make sure that you're using a `$.ready` wrap for your injected code.  If you still have problems, wrap your calls in a `setTimeout()` call so the DOM can catch up before you start calling things.  If you still have trouble, there's a problem with the script itself.

Comment: Also make sure you aren't redefining the $ operator.  This will happen if you are accidentally including jQuery twice, or if you are defining the $.fn before jQuery is included.

Comment: It was that simple. I was redefining it. If you want to post an answer Ill mark it for you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you aren't redefining the $ operator. This will happen if you are accidentally including jQuery twice, or if you are defining the $.fn before jQuery is included.